# How to store a values with a min and max size in c

Tags: c, cs50, strtol

I'm trying to create a program which asks for a `13-16` digit credit card number, and re-prompts if the user enters non-numerical values. So far my program works when I enter `16` digit values; however, it re-prompts if I enter anything less.

How do I get my program to accept a minimum of `13` digits and max of `16` digits?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    long cn;
    char buf[18], *endptr;

    do
    {
        printf("card number please: ");
        fgets(buf, 17, stdin);
        cn = strtol(buf, &endptr, 0);
    } while (*endptr != '\0' || endptr == buf);

    printf("%ld\n", cn);
}
```

Comment: The `fgets` function retains the new-line character `'\n'` at the end of the line. It also reads at most one character less as speicified, truncating the input if it doesn't fit. That means that for a short number, the chacater after the number is `'\n'`, not `'\0'`. The exception is a sixteen-digit number without surrounding spaces: Here, the `'\n'` doesn't fit and is not included in the string.

Comment: (The buffer length passed to `fgets` includes the space for the null terminator, so you could `fgets(buf, 18, stdin)` or, peraps even better `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)`. You could also make the buffer much larger and accept additional spaces and hyphens, because people tend to format their cc numbers inti four-digit chunks.)

Comment: Aa an aside: If you use `strtol` to check whether the input is a valid number, you should use base 10 explicitly. Otherwise, you might be surprised if you have a cc number with a leading zero and with 8's and 9's in it ...

Comment: `ptrdiff_t d; ... while( (d = endptr - buf) < 17 && d > 12 ... )`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) to locate the end of the `char` array in the `while` condition, you can return the size of the `char` array till it finds `'\0'` (or `'\n'` since you don't seem to be removing it from the array), you can then use this to set a minimum size for the input.

```
#include <string.h>
//...
do{
//...
while (strcspn(buf, "") < 14); //less than 13 chars will repeat the cycle
//...
```

You could also remove the `'\n'` from `buf`, in which case you can use `strlen`:

```
//...
do{
    fgets(buf, 17, stdin);
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
while (strlen(buf) < 13); //by removing '\n' you can use strlen
//...
```

The max size of `buf` will be `16` because you limit the size in `fgets` to `17`, so it will store `16` characters plus the null-terminator, you can reduce the size of your array to `17`, since the `18th` element is useless.

Also be aware that `long` is not always 8 bytes, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/limits.h

This being said, there is an inherit problem with the code, it consumes everything, aphabetic caracters, spaces, etc., so if you have an input of `1234 1234 1234 1234`, only `1234` will be converted by `strtol`.

In theexample below I'm removing everything that is not a digit and maintaining all your other specs:

[**Running sample**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/AvariciousAttachedExtensions)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    long long cn; //long long is never smaller than 8 bytes
    int i, c;
    char buf[17];

    do {
        i = 0;
        printf("card number please: ");
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF && strlen(buf) < 17) //max size 16
        {
            if (isdigit(c)) //only digits
                buf[i++] = c;
        }
        buf[i] = '\0';
    } while (strlen(buf) < 13); //min size 13

    cn = strtoll(buf, NULL, 10); //strtoll for long long

    printf("%lld\n", cn);
}
```

Comment: `"\0\n"` should be working the same as  `""`. And `strcspn(buf, "")` should be just `strlen(buf)`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, yes it's the same, only less explicit, `strlen()` can work but we need to remove `'\n'` from `buf`. I edited the answer to address this.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what is "explicit" about it. `"\0\n"` - the `\n` and terminating zero byte are just ignored and wasting memory. The `\0\n` could work if it would be `memcspn` function that could deal with zero bytes inside the memory.

Comment: @KamilCuk, explicit in the sense that it shows what we are looking for, but I see your point.

Comment: Note that `strcspn(buf, "")` is (probably) slower than `strlen(buf)` but produces the same result.  There's an outside chance the optimizer has been taught the equivalence, but it's more likely not an optimization it makes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, that seems about right, note that if there is a `'\n'` in the string, `strlen(buf)` will count it.

Answer (score 1):

If we're specifically talking about credit card numbers, you might want to enforce it only by the number of *digits* the user enters and not the number of total characters since credit card numbers are often entered with spaces or dashes between them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int numberofdigits(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, n = 0;
    while(str[i])
    {
        n += !!(isdigit(str[i]));
        i++;
    }

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int digits; 

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a credit card number: ");
        fgets(str, 100, stdin);

        digits = numberofdigits(str);
        printf("Read %d digits.\n", digits);
    }
    while((digits < 13) || (digits > 16));

    printf("Thanks for entering \"%s\"\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```